# Why Isn't This Getting Added to the Database?

Tags: python, html, sql, database, flask

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    post = request.form.get("question")
    option_1 = request.form.get("option1rename")
    option_2 = request.form.get("option2rename")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO posts (question, option1, option2) VALUES(:post, 
        option1, :option2)", post=post, option1=option_1, option2 = option_2)
    new_post = db.execute("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE question = :post", 
        post=post)
    print(new_post)
```

None of the form responses are getting added to the database. I can't for
the life of me figure out why. Can someone help?

Comment: Is this Flask? if so, you need to add flask tag

Comment: you need to commit your transaction :)

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: AttributeError: 'SQL' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: You forgot the `:` before the `option1` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your changes to the database.  See [this page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) from the docs about setting up a session.  Use the session to make your change.  Then it's just as simple as

```
session.add(your_change)
session.commit()
```

Without using a session, you can also try using

```
db.execute('COMMIT')
```

but I would recommend setting up the session.

Comment: I'm seeing this: RuntimeError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) cannot commit - no transaction is active [SQL: 'COMMIT']

And I read somewhere else that you don't need to commit on python?

Comment: A commit will be necessary in Python.  Check out that page in the docs about setting up a session.  It's pretty easy, and should be enough to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using sqlite so you dont have any session object, if your request arguments and table fields are fine `execute()` method will insert into table

```
elif request.method == "POST":
    post = request.form.get("question")
    option_1 = request.form.get("option1rename")
    option_2 = request.form.get("option2rename")
    db.execute(
       """INSERT INTO posts (question, option1, option2) VALUES(%s, 
          %s, %s)"""%(post, option_1, option_2))
    new_post = db.execute("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE question=%s", post)
    print(new_post)
```

Comment: I'm glad to see that I don't need to commit because that's the first i'm hearing of that, but what you suggested didn't fix it. I'm not sure what's wrong, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The form data is correct, there aren't any errors -- should there be?

Comment: can you try querry all posts `SELECT * FROM posts` ?

Comment: Actually, I'm seeing this: RuntimeError: This text() construct doesn't define a bound parameter named 'option1'

Comment: what are you doing you get RuntimeError? I am confused

Comment: I think it was a typo from changing the db.execute line, I didn't normally get that and it went away when I changed it back to how it was

Answer (score 0):

`db.execute(...)` doesn't return the rows fetched by the query. (In fact, per [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id14), the return value of `execute()` is undefined, and may differ from one database/library to another).

To get rows back from a `SELECT` query, you should iterate the cursor:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM ...")
for id, name in cursor:
    print (id, name)
```

(You can also use `fetchone()`, `fetchall()`, and other methods of the cursor, but I find it's usually easiest just to iterate the cursor with a `for ... in ...` loop).